# How does Akka Failure message work?

Tags: scala, akka

I use `Failure` message to let sender know that something went wrong. Responding back to sender with `sender() ! Failure(new RuntimeException())`

Does it throw an exception in the actor or on the sender side (or maybe neither)?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two `Failure` classes, `scala.util.Failure` is one of the types in the Scala `Try` API which is something like an alternative ADT for doing something like a `try-catch`. You can find more info about it in the [scaladocs for Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try)

The other one is part of `akka.actor.Status` which is a similar ADT but much simpler API signaling either a success with a value or a failure with an exception. It is used internally in Akka, but also by some of the public APIs for example the `pipe` pattern, which sends the result of a future as a message to an `ActorRef` ([in the Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future)).

When sending and receiving `Failure` nothing special is done automatically, so on the receiving side you would have to match on `Failure` to accept such a message in your actor.

Since it is possible to compose receive blocks you can define reusable handling of `Failure` yourself and combine with the regular receive block of an actor, [for example as described here](https://markatta.com/codemonkey/blog/2016/02/25/futures-plus-supervision-in-akka/)